# Flagging post as "should be closed because the topic belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network" offers a very limited list of sites

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, site-recommendation, migration

Stack Exchange users have the ability to flag a post to be closed because the post at hand has content that doesn't fit into the topic-range covered by the given Stack Exchange site.

The dialog that appears offers a **very, very limited** selection of other Stack Exchange sites which the person who's flagging the post has to choose from. I'm wondering why isn't there a better menu for this that offers more choices?

I have seen **a lot** of topics on Stack Overflow which are about general Linux stuff (installation, dual boot, etc.) and so on that definitely belong to **unix.stackexchange.com** but alas! I'm unable to find any way to point exactly where the post belongs to because of the limited (5-6) choice of Stack Exchange sites (most of which I might add are definitely not that popular).

Is this a reputation points limitation (I've just reached 2K on Stack Overflow) or is this really that useless as a feature?

Comment: Migration paths are site-specific and limited to sites that would be useful to *both* sites. If you think the migration paths for a specific site should be changed you should probably ask on that site's meta (sounds like meta.so).

Comment: If a question is off topic for a site, flag/vote to close it. If it's indeed a good question for another site, it'll find its way there eventually.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't know there is SO Meta.